# Remote desktop into portable Ubuntu running on Windows XP host

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I have an XP machine hosting a portable Ubuntu instance.  When I access the XP machine via remote desktop client, the portable Ubuntu applications are not starting up, failing with the error "DISPLAY environment variable not set".

How can I can view the portable Ubuntu GUI apps via remote desktop access to the host?

I am not allowed to run a VNC server on the host; remote desktop is the only access I have.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your Ubuntu shell:

setenv DISPLAY host_name:0.0

Answer (score 0):

FreeNX or the commercial version of NX (from nomachine,they offer a free version as well, just not open source) is the best for this, at least was the last time I checked.. it has good performance and you just need a small client... check out their website at: http://nomachine.com

and google around about freenx so you can become familiar with it.. it blows VNC away in terms of speed and performance.